# define tokens for Logical operators

Tags: java, parsing

I am in the process of creating a parser and I have defined the following clause.

```
private static final Pattern TOKENS = Pattern.compile("(\\s+)|(AND)|(OR)|(=)|(\\()|(\\))|(\\w+)|\'([^\']+)\'");
```

I need to add "AND NOT" token to the list, how do I do it? How do I represent white space between "AND NOT". Is it by using "\\s+" or by using the space directly. Looks like it doesn't recognize either ways when tried. Please suggest your inputs.

PS: It has to be NAND I believe but when asked about it I am told not to do things better.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to define the "NOT" operator? It could be applied to any expression and the "AND NOT" functionality would come naturally, among others.

Comment: what exactly do you expect/want from the regex? with all those otherwise unnecessary brackets it look like you want to capture the various tokens as different groups, but who knows... Please clarify what you want.

Comment: @Cinnam you are right. But there are lot of existing clauses that uses this condition. I cannot modify data, hence have to use "AND NOT" in my code.

Comment: @Bohemian Exactly. I need to capture these tokens into different groups.

Comment: Obviously I don't know the context here, but still - you will have to recognize the second argument of `AND NOT` anyway, as in `expr1 AND NOT expr2`. If you defined `NOT`, you would in this case have `expr1 AND expr3`, where `expr3` would be `NOT expr2`. Maybe there are reasons why you can't do this, but it seems to me you should be able to parse the exact same expressions with binary `AND` and unary `NOT` as you would with binary `AND NOT`